# Media feed with Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

Given two schemas, User and Post, structured so:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({{
    posts: [ {
        post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, required: false, ref: 'Post' }
      } ],
    followers: [ { user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' } } ],
    following: [ { user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' } } ],
  }
)

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, required: true },
  }
)
```

is there a way to efficiently query the last n posts of followed users?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is not optimized for bi-directional relationship; however, there are services like https://getstream.io/ which are designed for this kind of task. Consider migrating to stream, or, better yet, PostGres, MySQL, or any other sequel-based ORM.